# C language how to format a double to 2 digits after the decimal point?

Tags: c, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit floating point precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383817/limit-floating-point-precision)

In C language, I need to format a number to 2 digits after the decimal point from user input

For example:

```
 float x ; 
 printf("Enter number");
```

Let's suppose the user enters `4.54234635`

I need to print and process in the whole program: 
`4.54`

Thanks advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The complete list

```
Integer   display
%d      print as decimal integer
%6d     print as decimal integer, at least 6 characters wide
%f      print as floating point
%6f     print as floating point, at least 6 characters wide
%.2f    print as floating point, 2 characters after decimal point
```

With the required modification (`scanf("%.2f",&x);` in the last entry) will solve your problem

Comment: are you sure that the last one (%6.2f) works?

Comment: @orustammanapov i have currently removed it.,

Answer (score 18):

```
scanf("%.2f",&x);
```

And i think that will solve a problem

Comment: You cannot specify precision in a scanf function. But you can do that in a printf function.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
scanf("%.2f",&number);
```

or
    `printf("%.2f", number);`